# Xrdp: notify local user when a remote client is connected

Tags: rdp

I'm using xrdp on a xubuntu 11.10 machine, and successfully using Remmina to connect to it through the internet, from another xubuntu machine.

I would like to know, on the "server" machine, when a client has estabilished a connection. I couldn't find a way to do this in xrdp itself, so i thought about making a basic script using either zenity or notify-osd, but i don't know how i can launch it when a new rdp connection is created. Is there any way to trigger the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log`, the log file of (the session manager of) `xrdp`. That, combined with [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) (there's a package in ubuntu) should make it rather simple for you to write your script that then uses zenity or notify-osd.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure how this would appear in Xubuntu 11.10 however I will answer from experience using the Xubuntu 12.04 release. If you are using the `vino` application to serve desktop sharing, there is an option in the **Preferences** menu that will allow you to choose whether or not you would like to see notifications on the remote machine whenever users are connected. The **Preferences** menu is accessible through terminal by using the command `vino-preferences` as a superuser.

---

**Source:** [Ubuntu Linux Guide](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/remote-desktop-xubuntu-12-04)